# Choosing the right design pattern for computational nodes

Tags: python, multithreading, design-patterns, parallel-processing

I have to run several computations one after another in nodes A, B, C (D, E...). Each node corresponds to a class which has computational methods. In the following scheme, Ax, Bx, Cx are instances of A, B, C, and allow to run the computations, create some graphs etc.
[image: data flow]

I have the following requirements:

- I have a distributed system (e.g the Cloud), and I
  want the data in B1 to be processed after the data in A has been
  output and so on (the nodes have to be synchronized);
- All the computations in similar nodes can be performed in parallel;
- The results of the calculations in each node have to be saved and loaded at some point. This is useful in case a data in A has been calculated and after that the whole system shuts down. I want to be able to recover. The goal is also to be able to perform some maintenance by rerunning a past state of the system (for bug-tracking for example);
- I want to be able to monitor the current state of the system.

I was going to go for a state design pattern but it either does not seem sufficient, or I don't have the right idea for the implementation.

This is a huge subject in itself, so I would be glad to get ideas in terms of design patterns, multithreading handling, APIs, middlewares, etc.

(I am using Python by the way, but I didn't think it was very relevant to mention it)

Comment: Well, this is a strong contender for the 'Humongous question of Month' award :)  I'm not sure that any answer is possible without a full requirement spec, available tools/DB, protocols etc.  You need a team of systems designers instead of a blog post:)

Comment: SO is not for "design ideas" or "tips" or "hints", but for _concrete_ answers to _concrete_ questions. In short, we're not going to design your project for you!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of course you are not, I am just asking for pointers to relevant themes I might explore, keywords, something like that. Vivek's answer is constructive for example, yours is not.

Comment: `(I am using Python by the way, but I didn't think it was very relevant to mention it)` Actually, you just did! And it's a tag, too.

Comment: `pointers to relevant themes I might explore, keywords, something like that.` Yes, my point is, that is not what SO is for. Vivek posted a good answer, but the question should not have been posted, because SO is not a discussion forum or chat room. It is a technical Q&A. Please read the help to find out what SO is all about. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen plenty of questions on SO that were rather abstract, this is one of them. This is an abstract question on a design issue, and it could be applied to any language, but in my case I use python. Vivek's question, although good, does not address a general design but points to a python API (which is useful to me but maybe not for everyone). I never named my classes, or said what they were doing, they are just abstract computational nodes with generic needs. Since your criticism on the content doesn't hold, maybe you are not happy with the style I'm open to suggestions to improve it :).

Answer (score 1):

A successful design for python multitasking is queue-chaining model. If you have limited number of `steps(A,B,Cs)`. Then each task can be pushed into a queue, and once the queued task is complete, queue can signal completion. Thereby the data can be saved and pushed into subsequent queues.
 A relevant [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/).

Look into python demon threads to manage thread life-cycle.